# How to get value from json object using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following ajax call and the json feed it returns. how do I get the value of the data object i.e. FRI from the feed using jquery?

```
$.ajax({
    url: query,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json"
    success: function(data) {
        var day = // get data value from json
        $("#Day").val(day);
    }
});    

{
   "name":"workdays",
   "columns":[
      "day"
   ],
   "data":[
      [
         "FRI"
      ]
   ]
}
```

*** update ***

What would be the syntax be if the results were returned as jsonp as follows, how can you extract the value 'FRI' :

```
import({
  "Results":{
    "work_days":{
        "empid":100010918994,
        "day":"FRI"
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: You access it just as you would a normal Javascript object. I'm not too sure I understand what exactly you are asking... `data.data`?

Comment: day = data['data'] ?

Comment: it's json. (j)ava(s)cript (o)bject (n)otation. you access the decoded json like you would any other javascript data structure, because json **IS** javascript.

Comment: @MarcB: Saying "json IS javascript" is very misleading. Its syntax *looks like* a subset of JavaScript, but then some of JavaScript *looks like* C. So would we say JavaScript IS C? In fact, JSON/JavaScript are even more distinct since JSON is not in any way a programming language.

Comment: it may be a subset, but far too many people have the idea that json is magically special and requires special handling.

Comment: @squint Saying JavaScript is C is way more faulty than JSON is JavaScript. JSON is JavaScript `objects`

Comment: @MarcB: It does require special handling. It needs to be parsed just like any other serialized notation would. If we receive HTML and want to work with it as nodes, we need to have it parsed into the DOM. We wouldn't say HTML is the DOM though.

Comment: @Arg0n: JSON is not JavaScript objects. It's a textual representation of data that uses a syntax similar to that found in JavaScript (or other languages for that matter). There's a big difference between syntax and the data it represents.

Comment: @squint "The JSON format is syntactically identical to the code for creating JavaScript objects". I don't see how this is related to C, but i do see the relation to JS. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

Comment: @Arg0n: First, it isn't syntactically identical. If it was, we wouldn't have to use double quotes around property names, and there's one or two characters that aren't supported in JSON. But even it if was syntactically identical, it's just syntax. That doesn't mean they're the same thing. Again, there are syntactic examples of C in JavaScript. Does that mean when we point to those parts of a JavaScript program, we would call them "C"? No. We may point out the similarity, but we would recognize them as distinct technologies.

Comment: @squint So you can use C straight of the bat as JavaScript? I did not know that. But i do know you can take any JSON and assign it to a JavaScript object.

Comment: @Arg0n: Don't get snarky now. You can't use JSON straight out as JavaScript either. Because as JSON, it's all just Unicode text. You're confusing syntax with its underlying purpose. A JavaScript object is not its syntax. The object is the binary data created *from* the syntax. If you plug the JSON *syntax* into a JavaScript program, it's not really JSON anymore, because its context defines what it is, just like a `for` loop is defined by its context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just JavaScript, not jQuery.

```
var data = {
   "name":"workdays",
   "columns":[
      "day"
   ],
   "data":[
      [
         "FRI"
      ]
   ]
}

data.data[0][0]; //FRI
```

**UPDATE**

```
var obj = {
  "Results":{
    "work_days":{
        "empid":100010918994,
        "day":"FRI"
     }
  }
}

obj.Results.work_days.day //FRI
```

Comment: How can you get the same value if the results were returned as jsonp - see updated post.

Answer (score 3):

If the latter json is the json you get from the server, you can get the data like this:

```
var day = data.data[0][0];
```

This will put the value `FRI` in the variable `day`.

**EDIT:** If you use a recent browser, you can always do `console.log(data)` and look in your javascript console what is in the variable

Answer (score 1):

```
    $.ajax({
    url: query,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json"
    success: function(data) {
        var day = data.data[0][0] // get data value from json
        $("#Day").val(day);
    }
});    

{
   "name":"workdays",
   "columns":[
      "day"
   ],
   "data":[
      [
         "FRI"
      ]
   ]
}
```

Comment: OP is asking how to get 'FRI', not 'day'.

Answer (score 0):

json is javascript object, so you can access to any his property:

```
data.name
data.columns
data.data
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery data is a javascript object (hash). You can access the data as follow:

```
data.columns
```

Or

```
data["columns"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving the 'data' field

```
$.ajax({
url: query,
type: "GET",
dataType: "json"
success: function(data) {
    var day = data['data']; // get data value from json
    $("#Day").val(day);
}
});    

{
   "name":"workdays",
   "columns":[
   "day"
],
"data":[
   [
     "FRI"
   ]
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever checked the data.d variable?

```
success: function(data) {
   console.log(data.d); //prints the value
}
```